# Mapping the event data information to the plotting information in Shiny reactive plots

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

How to retrieve the original data used for plotting from the even_data information?

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot"),
  verbatimTextOutput("click")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    key <- row.names(mtcars)
    p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt, colour = factor(vs), key = key)) + 
        geom_point()
    ggplotly(p) %>% layout(dragmode = "select")

  })


  output$click <- renderPrint({
    d <- event_data("plotly_click")
    if (is.null(d)) "Click events appear here (double-click to clear)" else d
  })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When clicked on a point, the example output would be similar to

```
  curveNumber pointNumber    x    y       key
1           1           3 24.4 3.19 Merc 240D
```

Is there any way possible to map these information to the original dataset `mtcars`? How would the information in `curveNumber`, `pointNumber` will be useful and what do these fields mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `curveNumber` is the `colour = factor(vs)` variable, the `pointNumber`is the row number +1 within the group (0 or 1 of vs).

So using these two you can do the following:

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot"),
  verbatimTextOutput("click")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    key <- row.names(mtcars)
    p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt, colour = factor(vs), key = key)) + 
      geom_point()
    ggplotly(p) %>% layout(dragmode = "select")
  })
  output$click <- renderPrint({
    d <- event_data("plotly_click")
    if (is.null(d)) "Click events appear here (double-click to clear)" else mtcars %>% tibble::rownames_to_column() %>% filter(vs==d$curveNumber) %>% filter(row_number()==d$pointNumber+1)

  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Or, second option, you need to extract the `key`from `event_data` and subset mtcars like this:

```
output$click <- renderPrint({
    d <- event_data("plotly_click")
    if (is.null(d)) "Click events appear here (double-click to clear)" 
    else mtcars[rownames(mtcars) == d$key,]
  })
```

The complete app:

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot"),
  verbatimTextOutput("click")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    key <- row.names(mtcars)
    p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt, colour = factor(vs), key = key)) + 
      geom_point()
    ggplotly(p) %>% layout(dragmode = "select")
  })
  output$click <- renderPrint({
    d <- event_data("plotly_click")
    if (is.null(d)) "Click events appear here (double-click to clear)" else mtcars[rownames(mtcars) == d$key,]
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks! But, My question was mainly focused on getting it by using `curveNumber`, `pointNumber`.

Comment: Also, pls make sure to ask explicitly what u want, that is ur Question was: "Is there any way possible to map this information to the original dataset mtcars" which was satisfied already by the first submit (I used the key). The second submit with curveNumber and pointNumber.

Comment: pls note minor edit: mtcars %>% tibble::rownames_to_column() %>% filter(vs==d$curveNumber) %>% filter(row_number()==d$pointNumber+1)